# How to refresh PWA icon on Android home screen?

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, homescreen

I just updated the icon of my PWA and I want to see how it looks like on Android home screen immediately, without having to wait for days. However, the icon does not want to refresh.

This is what I did in order to refresh the icon on Android home screen (and did **not** work):

```
-change the icons hosted on the server
-update the urls of manifest.json, pwa-service-worker.js, pwa-start.js by adding a ?v=x parameter
-update the urls of the icons in manifest.json and in the html meta tags  by adding a ?v=x parameter
-clear PWA cache on android
-uninstalled PWA on android
-cleared website cache from chrome Android
-installed PWA again from chrome
```

After doing all this, when installing again the PWA, Android home screen still shows the previous icon.
[image]

My questions are:

1. How can I refresh the PWA icon for myself? (I have access to my own phone)
2. How can I do it for all users? (I don't have access to their phone)

Answer (score 0):

After replacing your images or its paths, uninstall and reinstall your PWA. Delete all data from the installation if you get any prompts.

When you reinstall, it should be using your new images.

- On windows I had a bug where the taskbar icon would reset back to the old one when right clicked. All I had to do was reinstall and install for a second time and it would keep my new icon