# How to change PWA "add to home screen" icon

Tags: google-chrome, icons, progressive-web-apps, vite

I'm trying to code a Vite PWA and so far I have been able to configure all icons, including the maskable one.

I have no idea why this specific icon is showing as a black circle when I try to install the app in an Android device from Google Chrome. I have icons for all the resolutions I found to be relevant: 72x72, 96x96, 144x144, 192x192, 512x512, also the favicon, the svg one and the apple touch icon. I have no other issue with the icons other than the "add to home screen"/install/loading one in Chrome.

I have tried to clear the browser cache and try to install again. I also have pushed a new version of the manifest with al the file names ending in "?v=2" with no result.

I also have found a similar question, but the only answer does not fix the issue:
[How to refresh PWA icon on Android home screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73674537/how-to-refresh-pwa-icon-on-android-home-screen)